# How is std::getline() equated with bool?

Tags: c++, stl, operator-keyword, getline, conversion-operator

I'm a `std::getline(...)` virgin and having consulted documentation and example at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), I'm confused by example code such as this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile("sample.txt");

    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    return 0;
}
```

...specifically the while statement: `while (std::getline(infile, line))`.

The noted documentation says the return value of `std::getline(std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input, ...)` is `input`, i.e. a reference to the first argument.

How, then, can the return value of `getline` be used as the while loop's condition, which needs to be of type `bool`?

Does `std::ifstream` implement an `operator bool()`?

Comment: ‘*Does `std::ifstream` implement an `operator bool()`?*’ Why [yes it does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), and you can [look it up at that same website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

Comment: "Does `std::ifstream` implement an `operator bool()`?" [Close. Inherited one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

Comment: And pre c++11 it had `operator void*`.

Comment: Good point @PaulRooney , but seriously. Who remembers that far back?

Comment: For reasons of historical interest only :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does std::ifstream implement an operator bool()?

[It does:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)

> Checks whether the stream has no errors. <...> Returns true if the stream has no errors and is ready for
>   I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.
>
> This operator makes it possible to use streams and functions that
>   return references to streams as loop conditions, resulting in the
>   idiomatic C++ input loops such as `while(stream >> value) {...}` or
>   `while(getline(stream, string)){...}`